# What does \usebibmacro{bibindex} in BibliographyDrivers do?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographystyle

I am trying to define a custom bibliography style for my university courses and for this I want to understand what other styles do . Virtually every *.bbx file I looked at starts its Bibliography drivers with `\usebibmacro{bibindex}`.

However, whether I add it or not has no observable effect for me and I could not find out from the documentation what it actually does or where it is declared.

Here is the MWE I used to test if I get some observable effect.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[style=german]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=geschichtsfrkl, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}\newblock%  
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit*{\addcommad\addspace}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{location+edition+year}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{erlerStraftheorieZychaRegister1998,
  title = {Straftheorie - Zycha: Register},
  author = {Erler, Adalbert},
  location = {{Berlin}},
  date = {1998},
}

@book{ganshofWasIstLehnswesen1975,
  title = {Was ist das Lehnswesen?},
  author = {Ganshof, F. L.},
  location = {{Darmstadt}},
  edition = {4},
  date = {1975},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{ganshofWasIstLehnswesen1975} \\
\fullcite{erlerStraftheorieZychaRegister1998} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but ideally you would have a `%` in `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{` to make it read `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%`. This avoids an undesirable space (which is most likely already countered by other means, but it is still good style to avoid it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bibmacro `bibindex` is defined in [`biblatex.def` (ll. 2409-2413 in v3.19)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/24a94f8f608872e11d259d7c581fc90ea76542a5/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2409-L2413). Its definition is

```
\newbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}
```

which means it only does something if `\ifbibindex` is true. `\ifbibindex` is true if the `indexing` option is set so that bibliography entries are to be indexed (i.e. if the option is set to `bib` or `true`). In that case, the macro indexes the `labelname` and the `indextitle`.

You probably didn't see an effect because you have indexing turned off, but it is good practice to keep that macro in for those cases where one wants indexing.

---

If you write your own bibriver it's usually a good idea to keep all of the

```
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
```

that are used at the beginning of all standard bibdrivers. I feel similarly about the tail

```
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

Of course you may have requirements that may necessitate change here, but for the vast majority of cases the code is probably better left in there.

Comment: Are we talking about the types of indexing you would do with the makeidx package?

Comment: @FChris Yes, for example. If activated `biblatex` would (by default at least) simply issue `\index` commands for the relevant entries. But of course that can be configured for all sorts of different indexing packages/interfaces.